# New Badge suggestion - Bounty Hunter

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

So, bounty's are great and all but many times they are more involved and time consuming to answer. Many times the bounty offer is not enough to attract interest / participation or the question itself is mismatched with the bounty and not enough to generate interest / participation.

So in order to attract additional interest / participation I am suggesting the creation of a new badge

**Bounty Hunter**

The main purpose is to motivate people to participate is answering questions with lower bounties, questions where the bounty is low and the question is complex, or questions that simply do not draw enough participation regardless of the bounty.

I propose the structure be as follows:

Bronze: 5 Answers on bounty questions after the bounty period has started and before it has expired with an answer score > 2 with a minimum of 1 bounty awarded to your answers

Silver: 50 Answers on bounty questions after the bounty period has started and before it has expired with at least half having an answer score > 2 with a minimum of 10 bounties awarded to your answers

gold: 100 Answers on bounty questions after the bounty period has started and before it has expired with at least half having an answer score > 2 with a minimum of 30 bounties awarded to your answers

The above is just a suggestion but I think it would be cool to have a bounty hunter badge and possibly have it increase participation in bounties. It sucks to create a bounty and have it go un-awarded or go to an answer that does not answer the question just because it was the only one and someone drive by upvoted it.

This does not have to be limited to this stack but not sure how to suggest a badge across the network.

Comment: full network meta may get you more reaction than the limited scope of our salesforce stackexchange community: https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke - Sorry, just found https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges - which suggests a similar idea was declined so I guess its a lost cause

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges

Comment: Status declined. :(

Comment: @AdrianLarson - yea boo....